# jquery ajax contentType:false not making the boundary tag for jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-type, put

I have added contentType as false for my jQuery ajax request. I am sending

```
$.ajax({
        url : "http://groc.cloudapp.net:8000/api/view/"+tile_vert_id+"/"+tileId,
        type: "PUT",
        data :updatedemoData,
        processData: false,
        cacheControl: "no-cache",
        contentType: false,
        success : function(data,textStatus,jqXHR)
        {
            alert("Yo");
            console.log("successdata: ",data);
            $($caseToEdit).find(".tile-name").text(updatedemoData.name);
            $($caseToEdit).find(".tile-des").text(updatedemoData.description);
            $($caseToEdit).find(".v-url").text(updatedemoData.url);
            $(".ajax-loader").hide();


        },
        error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
            $(".ajax-loader").hide();
            alert("error in loading!");
        }
    });
```

and I am sending Formdata object for data

```
var updatedemoData = new FormData();
        updatedemoData.name = demoName;
        updatedemoData.description = demoText;
        updatedemoData.videoordemo = tileType;
        updatedemoData.url = demoUrl;
```

but when I run the same code in the browser console, I am getting the boundary tag. Without boundary tag, the data is not getting saved in server.

I am expecting something like this with boundary tag

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryiBHhkxeJP2Vc7a5Q
```

but the content type is actually

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Any suggestions

Comment: I think appending param in FormData should be using `.append()` method..try using that.. like this `updatedemoData.append("name", demoName);`

Comment: it will work fine even with the method mentioned in question that is `updatedemoData.name = "some name"`

Answer (score 2):

Anyways I am able to get it working when I changed the above URL in a local variable.

```
var ajaxUrl = "http://groc.cloudapp.net:8000/api/view/"+tile_vert_id+"/"+tileId,

$.ajax({
    url : ajaxUrl ,
    type: "PUT",
    data :updatedemoData,
    processData: false,
    ... 
});
```

The URL had no error when I tried consoling the same code before.But I don't understand what could be the exact reason for above code to work.